# Primefaces - É possível mudar a cor de gráfico chartline?

Tags: primefaces

Uso primefaces 5.2 e tenho o seguinte gráfico: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que gostaria de fazer é deixar a parte abaixo da linha, em azul, mas não encontrei nada parecido na web, alguém sabe se isso é possível e como faze-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode customizar quase todos os elementos utilizando apenas declarações CSS. Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
canvas.jqplot-series-canvas {
    background: rgba(65, 143, 199, 0.11);
}
```

Fiz um exemplo utilizando o [`showcase do primefaces`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/line.xhtml). Segue uma screenshot do resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Atualização**

Após explicação mais detalhada do problema, foi verificado que a solução é o uso de outro tipo de gráfico, conhecido como [`gráfico de área`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/area.xhtml).

Comment: Romulo, o problema é que eu quero mudar essa cor independente dos pontos, é um gráfico dinâmico, quero deixa-lo azul abaixo da linha sempre, isso é possível?

Comment: pelo que entendi vc esta mudando a cor apenas para pontos específicos.

Comment: você chegou a fazer o teste? esse elemento representa todo o background do gráfico. caso não seja exatamente o que você precisa, envie uma imagem para exemplificar melhor

Comment: É um gráfico de reservatório, quero que a parte ABAIXO da linha fique azul. Mas só a parte que fica embaixo da linha, isso para representar a água.

Comment: @Jason Você provavelmente escolheu o tipo de gráfico errado então. Acredito que o mais interessante para o seu caso é utilizar o [`gráfico de area`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/area.xhtml)

Comment: Realmente Romulo.

Comment: @Romulo Sugiro atualizar a sua resposta com a sugestão de outro tipo de gráfico. Não tem nenhum problema em fazer isso, pois nem sempre a melhor resposta é aquela que responde literalmente ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: @Jason Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Se a resposta do Romulo lhe ajudaram a resolver o problema, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como certa. Além de garantir alguns pontos de reputação para ambos, você ajuda a outras pessoas que visitarem essa pergunta futuramente a saber que o problema foi solucionado.